# AngularJS UI State Provider Resolve States

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, resolve

Trying to leverage AngularJS UI States and using resolves to set vars.
I currently have this in my app.js --

```
var stateConfig = ['stateHelperProvider', function(stateHelperProvider) {
  stateHelperProvider
  .state({
    name: 'events',
    url: '/' + artistSlug,
    templateUrl: "/templates/events/events.html",
    controller: "EventsCtrl",
    resolve: {
      artist: function(artist) {
        return artist.getArtist();
      }
    }
  });
```

Within the EventsCtrl I have the following --

```
    angular.module('artist.events.controllers', []).
controller('EventsCtrl', ['$filter', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$location', 'artist', function($filter, $rootScope, $scope, $state, $stateParams, $location, artist) {
    $scope.artist = artist;
```

On my local dev machine, it resolves correctly. Within prod however, $scope.artist returns nothing. I believe it could be related to compiling based on precompiling and minification. Unsure how to fix though. Thoughts?

Comment: can you provide the code where you use `$scope.artist` which returns nothing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're using a build tool like [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate), you will have to provide the DI annotation for the `resolve` properties, ie

```
resolve: {
    artist: ['artist', function(artist) {
        return artist.getArtist();
    }]
}
```

---

I would consider renaming your resolve property so it is different to your `artist` service. At least that way, you would have gotten an error about an unresolved provider. Something like `eventArtist` would be my pick.

Comment: thank you! the dependency injection issue with prod was the culprit!